# How can I avoid loop break in web scrapping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, custom-error-pages

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import pandas as pd
import time
import urllib.error

book_ids = ["9781408110416","9789604249671","9781405950305"]

def get_description(book_id): 
    my_urls = 'https://www.bookdepository.com/Enid-Blytons-Christmas-Tales-Enid-Blyton/' + book_id
    source = urlopen(my_urls).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    description = soup.find('div', class_='item-img-content')

    if description:
        return description
    else:
        return "[No description"

for book_id in book_ids: 
    print(book_id)
    print(get_description(book_id))

    time.sleep(2)
```

The error I get -

```
HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Hello, I am working on  script to scrap image urls from bookdepository. My main problem is that certain books return 404 because they are not available on the platform.

How can I keep the script simply go to the next code and not stop the entire loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code in `get_description()` function in a `try` and `except` block. Something like this,

```
def get_description(book_id): 
    my_urls = 'https://www.bookdepository.com/Enid-Blytons-Christmas-Tales-Enid-Blyton/' + book_id

    try:
      source = urlopen(my_urls).read()
      soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
      description = soup.find('div', class_='item-img-content')

      if description:
          return description
      else:
          return "[No description"
    except:
      pass
```

Now if the code encounters an erorr, it'll just skip that `book_id` and move to the enxt one.